# How to add drivers in node inputs in python?

Tags: python, node-editor, drivers

I am trying to add a driver in a node entry in the World.
The following script fail with 
"TypeError: bpy_struct.driver_add(): property "inputs" not animatable
"
I can't find sample of similar code. Any help?

```
import bpy
scn = bpy.context.scene

wd = scn.world
nodes = wd.node_tree.nodes
wd.node_tree.nodes.clear() 

DR1 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeMath')
drv = DR1.driver_add("inputs",0)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Drive the `default_value` property of a particular input channel.**

```
>>> n = C.scene.world.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeMath")
>>> d = n.inputs[0].driver_add("default_value")

>>> d.driver.expression
'0.5'

>>>
```